# How can I sort images based on both date and parent folder?

Tags: sorting, batch-file, vbscript, cmd, backup

I have been tasked with creating a monthly backup of photos, these need to be moved from where they are to somewhere else, sorted by date into folders, then burnt to disk in monthly lots.
In theory this should be simple, even though its a new process and we have roughly a year worth of photos, once its been done once we can just run it every month from now on.

So first thought is:
Copy from location "A" to location "B", sort into sub-folders based on created date "MONTH\YEAR", burn each folder to disk.

This is quite simple and would have been done now if that was the case, my issue is this:
All the photos are from other companies who we provide a service for, there are ~15 companies and each have their own folder. Inside each folder is 5 more folders, ONE of which has the images, others have config files database backups etc etc.

So as an example the structure is:

> ─Data
>     ├─Company1
>     │   ├───IMAGES
>     │   ├───Other1
>     │   └───Other2
>     ├─Company2
>     │   ├───IMAGES
>     │   ├───Other1
>     │   └───Other2
>     └─Company3
>         ├───IMAGES
>         ├───Other1
>         └───Other2

So within each "IMAGE" folder are the photos which *aren't* sorted by date. I need to copy only those folders to a structure which looks like this:

> ──Backups
>       ├─01-15
>       │   ├───Company1
>       │   ├───Company2
>       │   └───Company3
>       ├─02-15
>       │   ├───Company1
>       │   ├───Company2
>       │   └───Company3
>       └─03-15
>           ├───Company1
>           ├───Company2
>           └───Company3

That way I can simple burn each months folder to its own disk and in it all the images are sorted by company.

So create a folder with name of "MONTH-YEAR" then inside that, create folders for each company "Company1" "Company2" etc and then in each of those folders have the photos from that company and that month.

I have attempted to write this in batch to almost 0 success. Though I no longer have the code(deleted it in annoyance after it not working a few too many times :/ ), it used a lot of nested IF statements and variables being set to maintain the name of the parent folder of the parent folder etc etc then looping around to do the whole process on the next folder...

So long story short, I need some way to script the moving of images into folders based on date and the name of the folder two levels above it. Also if it could create the folders where its being copied to that would be great.
Even if someone could just provide some pointers of where to start in batch(or VBS), or some psuedo code which I can work off of I would GREATLY appreciate it.

Thank you very much,
this confused newbie!

Comment: Where does the date come from? The last modified date? Created date? Other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, instead of scraping the company name by the grandparent folder of the image, would it be acceptable to scrape it by the child of "Data"?  This can be done with some [string manipulation](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php) in a subroutine.

In a `for` loop, `%%~tX` has the last modified date of each file.  Employing a couple of nested `for` loops to split that string by space, then by slashes can massage the date into `MM-YYYY` very easily.  **Edit:** I [looked up the date format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country) for the New Zealand locale, and I think I've got the script configured correctly to scrape month and year for you.  Give it a shot and see how it works.  (If I were trying to make this locale-agnostic, I'd probably query `wmic datafile` for each file, but that'd be a bit of a job.  Let me know if you need it.)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "source=c:\Data"
set "destination=d:\Backup"

:: for every image file recursively in %source%
for /r "%source%" %%I in (*.jpg *.png *.gif *.bmp *.xcf *.psd) do (

    rem :: get company name from directory 1 level within "Data"
    call :getCompany company "%%~dpI"

    rem :: get month-year from file last modified date
    rem :: note: assumes ~t is in format of dd/mm/yy hh:mm
    for /f %%a in ('echo %%~tI') do (
        for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=/" %%x in ('echo %%a') do (
            set "fdate=%%x-%%y"
        )
    )

    set "folder=%destination%\!fdate!\!company!\"
    if not exist "!folder!" md "!folder!"

    <NUL set /P "=Copying %%~nxI to !fdate!\!company!\... "
    >NUL copy "%%~fI" "!folder!"
    echo Done.
)

goto :EOF

:getCompany <var_to_set> <path>
setlocal
set "company=%~2"
set "company=%company:*Data\=%"
set company=%company:\=&rem.%
endlocal & set "%~1=%company%"
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly, only modification I made was to change it from making a folder called "MM-YYYY" to "YYYY-MM" as suggested in the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

These solutions assume directory listings show file time stamps as "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS PM". The code would have to be modified if the time stamp format is different for your locale.

I strongly recommend that you name your date folders using YYYY-MM format so that they sort chronologically. Also, you should not use 2 digit years - I lived through the Y2K nightmare - it isn't worth it.

If the dates come from each file's last modified date, then it is fairly easy - the ~t modifier provides the last modified date of the file:

```
%= Iterate company folders =%
for /d %%D in ("Data\*") do (

  %= Iterate images under company folder =%
  for %%F in ("%%D\IMAGES\*") do (

    %= Parse last modified month and year for the file =%
    for /f "delims=/ tokens=1,3" %%A in ("%%~tF") do (

      %= Create the destination folder - ignore error if already exists =%
      md "Backup\%%B-%%A\%%~nxD" 2>nul

      %= Move the file =%
      move "%%F" "Backup\%%B-%%A\%%~nxD" >nul
    )
  )
)
```

If you want the creation date instead, then it is a bit more complicated. I use the DIR /TC option to get the creation date, and the date and file name must be parsed from the DIR listing.

```
%= Iterate company folders =%
for /d %%A in ("Data\*") do (

  %= Iterate images under company folder, parsing out created date and file name =%
  for /f "tokens=1,4*" %%B in (
    'dir /a-d /tc "%%A\images"^|findstr /rc:"^[^ ]"'
  ) do (

    %= Parse the month and year from created date =%
    for /f "delims=/ tokens=1,3" %%E in ("%%B") do (

      %= Create the destination folder - ignore error if already exists =%
      md "Backup\%%C-%%B\%%~nxA" 2>nul

      %= Move the file =%
      move "%%A\images\%%D" "Backup\%%C-%%B\%%~nxA" >nul
    )
  )
)
```

It is possible to use WMIC to get the creation date or last modified date in a locale agnostic manner. But the coding becomes quite complex, with lots of arcane tricks required to get the desired result in an efficient manner. The code below assumes you want the creation date. To use last modified date, simply change `creationDate` to `lastModified`.

```
@echo off
:: FOR loop variables must be expanded with delayed expansion off
:: otherwise values containing ! will be corrupted
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

%= Iterate company folders =%
for /d %%D in ("Data\*") do (

  %= Parse drive, company, and image path info                    =%
  %= Enable delayed expansion to access variables set within loop =%
  %= Escape \ in path for use with WMIC                           =%
  set "drive=%%~dD"
  set "company=%%~nxD"
  set "imagePath=%%~pnxD"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  set "imagePath=!imagePath:\=\\!\\IMAGES\\"

  %= Iterate images and creation dates for files under company folder using WMIC   =%
  %= Two FOR /F loops are used to eliminate trailing <CR> character from each line =%
  %= The trailing <CR> is an odd artifact of conversion of WMIC unicode output     =%
  for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%A in (
    'wmic datafile where "drive='!drive!' and path='!imagePath!'" get creationDate^, name 2^>nul'
  ) do for /f "tokens=1*" %%B in ("%%A") do (

    %= Disable delayed expansion again to protect ! =%
    setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

    %= Save the date and file info. The file will have trailing spaces, but that =%
    %= is OK because Windows ignores trailing spaces and dots in file names      =%
    set "date=%%B"
    set "image=%%C" 

    %= Re-enable delayed expansion and parse out year and month to compute destination =%
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    set "destination=Backup\!date:~0,4!-!date:~4,2!\!company!"

    %= Create the destination folder - ignore error if already exists =%
    md "!destination!" 2>nul

    %= Move the file =%
    move "!image!" "!destination!" >nul

    %= Pop the setlocal stack to get back to state before inner loop started =%
    endlocal
    endlocal
  )

  %= Pop the setlocal stack to get back to state before outer loop started =%
  endlocal
)
```

The job becomes much easier if you use my [JREN.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) utility, which can parse and format file timestamps in a locale agnostic manner. JREN.BAT is primarily used to rename files using regular expressions. But it has a list mode that allows you to transform a file name into nearly anything, without renaming, which can then be parsed with FOR /F.

The code below uses the creation date. Change `created` to `modified` if you want to use the last modified date instead.

```
@echo off

:: JREN does most of the work.
:: /LIST option lists the final "rename" value, without renaming anything
:: /P specifies root path
:: /S iterates all sub-folders
:: /PM determines which sub-folders to look at, /P: matches the root path
:: /J treats replacement value as JScript code
:: The "^.*" search matches the entire file name
:: The "ts({dt:'created',fmt:'{yyyy}-{mm} '})+path()" replacement 
::    gets and formats the creation date using WMI
::    followed by the full path to the image file
:: The JREN output looks like:  YYYY-MM fullPathToImage

for /f "tokens=1*" %%A in (
  'jren "^.*" "ts({dt:'created',fmt:'{yyyy}-{mm} '})+path()" /list /j /s /p "Data" /pm "/P:\*\IMAGES"'
) do (

  %= Get the company name from the fullImagePath =%
  for %%C in ("%%B\..\..") do (

    %= Create the destination folder - ignore error if already exists =%
    md "Backup\%%A\%%~nxC" 2>nul

    %= Move the file =%
    move "%%B" "Backup\%%A\%%~nxC" >nul
  )
)
```

Comment: EDIT - Added methods that will work with any date format, regardless of locale. The first uses WMIC, and is complicated. The second uses my JREN.BAT utility - much simpler :)

Comment: While I appreciate the help, and the introduction to JREN.BAT (which I will use in the future and can see being useful) the other answer I chose for its simplicity.

Comment: @KeeghanMcGarry - rojo's answer is perfectly fine, but my first pure batch solution seems every bit as simple to me. Different strokes I guess :)